# Go template/html iteration to generate table from struct

Tags: html, templates, reflection, iterator, go

Given a collection of structs, how can I use the "range" template iterator to print out a table that assigns a row per struct, and a column per field value without explicity naming the fields?

```
container := []Node

type Node struct {
    Contact_id        int
    Employer_id       int
    First_name        string
    Middle_name       string
    Last_name         string
}
```

Template Code:

```
{{range .container}}

<tr>
<td>{{.Prefix}}</td>
<td>{{.First_name}}</td>
<td>{{.Middle_name}}</td>
<td>{{.Last_name}}</td>

<td>{{.Contact_id}}</td>
<td>{{.Employer_id}}</td>

</tr>
{{end}}
```

---

When I try iterating through the values using

```
{{range .container}}
 {{range .}}
 <td>{{.}}</td> 
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

I am told that I cannot iterate over the Values. 
Is there any clean way to do this?

Comment: What is `.container.Nodes` in your code? In case you want to iterate over `container`, just use `.container`.

Comment: my mistake, I've corrected the example above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the `html/template`, you cannot iterate over the fields in a struct. In the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) for the package, you can read:

> {{range pipeline}} T1 {{end}}
>   The value of the pipeline must be an array, slice, map, or channel.

That is, Pipeline cannot be a struct. Either you need to:

- use an intermediate type, eg. `[][]interface{}`, as container variable that you pass to the template
- type out each  cell separately as you've shown
- create a template function that converts struct values to some type you can iterate over

Since a struct is defined at compile-time and won't change its structure during runtime, iteration is not necessary and wouldn't make things more clear in the template. I would advise against it.

**Edit**

But sometimes reflection is a good thing. Brenden also pointed out that you can actually let range iterate over the value returned from a function. If using reflection, this would be the easiest approach.

Full working example using a template function:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

type Node struct {
    Contact_id  int
    Employer_id int
    First_name  string
    Middle_name string
    Last_name   string
}

var templateFuncs = template.FuncMap{"rangeStruct": RangeStructer}

// In the template, we use rangeStruct to turn our struct values
// into a slice we can iterate over
var htmlTemplate = `{{range .}}<tr>
{{range rangeStruct .}} <td>{{.}}</td>
{{end}}</tr>
{{end}}`

func main() {
    container := []Node{
        {1, 12, "Accipiter", "ANisus", "Nisus"},
        {2, 42, "Hello", "my", "World"},
    }

    // We create the template and register out template function
    t := template.New("t").Funcs(templateFuncs)
    t, err := t.Parse(htmlTemplate)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, container)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}

// RangeStructer takes the first argument, which must be a struct, and
// returns the value of each field in a slice. It will return nil
// if there are no arguments or first argument is not a struct
func RangeStructer(args ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    if len(args) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(args[0])
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return nil
    }

    out := make([]interface{}, v.NumField())
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        out[i] = v.Field(i).Interface()
    }

    return out
}
```

Output:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Accipiter</td>
    <td>ANisus</td>
    <td>Nisus</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>my</td>
    <td>World</td>
</tr>
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/38W6Lw3zSE)

Comment: The idea is basically to have the app go from query response to datatable with minimal intervention. I am scanning data from a SQL query directly into a struct, then reflecting out a list of headers to iterate over in the template to create the thead.
Thank you for the response, I can now stop banging my head against this. I'm going to port the struct to value arrays and iterate over those.

Comment: Then you can use the `reflect` package to populate a intermediate `[][]interface{}` variable that you pass to the template, much in the same way that you use reflection for the headers. I will add an example of it when time is given.

Comment: Write your own template method `rangeStruct` with http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs and use `reflect` as mentioned above. Eg: https://github.com/brendensoares/revel/blob/master/template.go

Comment: @Brenden I dismissed it because I thought that wasn't possible. Trying it out, I see that you can indeed have a Template function return a struct to iterate over! That is a much nicer solution. I will add it

Comment: @Derek I added a working example using a custom template function as suggested by Brenden. I missed that it was possible to range over function return values.

Comment: Awesome--I bet a lot of folks will find this useful.