# go html template table

Tags: html, loops, templates, go

I want to make the table in HTML in go package "temlate" and i want to add rows in loop, but i didn't find how doing this

my code:

```
package main
import (
     "net/http"
     "html/template"
)
type Devicevalue_view struct {
    Devicetype string
    Iddevice   string
    Devicename string
    Oidname    string
    Value      string
  }
func page_1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    for i:=1; i<10; i++{    
        data := Devicevalue_view{
            Devicetype: "devicetype",
            Iddevice: "iddevice",
            Devicename: "devicename",
            Oidname: "oidname",
            Value: "value",
        }   
        tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("./index.html")
        tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    }   
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/table", page_1) 
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

i'm getting this :

```
Devices
Type    Name    Param   Time    Value
devicetype  iddevice    devicename  oidname value
Devices
Type    Name    Param   Time    Value
devicetype  iddevice    devicename  oidname value
...
```

but i want somthing like this

```
Devices
Type    Name    Param   Time    Value
devicetype  iddevice    devicename  oidname value
devicetype  iddevice    devicename  oidname value
...
```

I don't undestand how connect all cells in one table

index.html:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HzEL0i3VhiafPzlV8iC0kU8WaSQwoYZY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should first aggregate your data into a slice, then, in the template you can use the `range` action to loop over that slice and render individual rows. Currently you're rendering each row individually in a separate `index.html` file, that's just wrong. Also you should include the template code in the question and not link to it outside SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go template/html iteration to generate table from struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991124/go-template-html-iteration-to-generate-table-from-struct)

Answer (score 9):

Because you are executing template inside `for loop`. Also you can pass a single `struct`. To pass array you have to pass it as a member of the struct.

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

type Data struct {
    Items []Devicevalue_view
}

type Devicevalue_view struct {
    Devicetype string
    Iddevice   string
    Devicename string
    Oidname    string
    Value      string
}

func page_1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := Data{}
    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        view := Devicevalue_view{
            Devicetype: "devicetype",
            Iddevice:   "iddevice",
            Devicename: "devicename",
            Oidname:    "oidname",
            Value:      "value",
        }

        data.Items = append(data.Items, view)
    }

    tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("./index.html")
    tmpl.Execute(w, data)
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/table", page_1)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Also you have to iterate through data and generate row dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Param</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    {{ range .Items}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ .Devicetype }}</td>
            <td>{{ .Iddevice }}</td>
            <td>{{ .Devicename }}</td>
            <td>{{ .Oidname }}</td>
            <td>{{ .Value }}</td>
        </tr>
    {{ end}}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @СергейВласов check the html file also.

Comment: Accept the answer it will help others.